# Trigonometry - know height difference of two points relative to an origin

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, vectors, real-numbers

(Concerned to vertical coordinates)

If we got an origin point as reference, and want to know the height difference between two points, `a` the higher, `b` the lower...

If both or at least one of the two is positive (above the origin),
then with: `a - (b)` we got the difference of height between them.

Example: `20 - (-2) = 22`
or `20 - (+2) = 18`

But if both are negative (below the origin), then `b - (a)` would be the formula.

Example: `-2 - (-20) = 18`

What is the formula that works for both scenarios?

I'm comparing the vertical components of two tridimensional vectors to get its height difference. Both are real numbers (3.14, etc).

Can use both a formula involving two vectors or two reals.

Comment: Maybe $|b - a|$?

Comment: "*$a$ the higher, $b$ the lower*" $\;-\;$ Then in your example with negative numbers $-2$ is higher than $-20$, so $a=-2,b=-20$ and the height difference is $a-b=-2+20=18\,$ (not $b-a$ as you wrote).

Comment: thx for answer, what is $?